# How to find distinct values for another column which has critical data?

Tags: sql, netezza

I currently have a column with has account numbers which are unique
I want to create unique values for each account unique account number in another column , so that I can use those to get the count of distinct values .

For example :

```
Account number  unique value 
12345.                    67
56738.                   87
28373.                   58 
28373.                   58
```

So when I take distinct of the unique value column I get the same distinct count of that distinct count of account number .
So here the distinct count will be 3

Comment: Can't you just number them 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: Can you tell me the logic if it’s one two three ? Will it say 3 3 if it’s repeated ?

Comment: You say "I currently have a column with has account numbers which are unique". Do 1, 2, 3... there.

Comment: How to number each row of my account number could you tell me that logic ?

Answer (score 0):

`dense_rank()` should do what you want:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by account_number) as unique_id
from t;
```

Note that this can change over time as new accounts are added or removed.  My recommendation if this is an issue is to create a separate table `account_numbers` that has an integer primary key.  Use the primary key for the unique number.